# What is the restriction of a function $f$ to a closed subscheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, divisors-algebraic-geometry

I am confused by the following definition (Definition 7.7.3 in the book “Algebraic Geometry II” by Mumford and Oda (in page 258 in [its draft](https://www.google.co.jp/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiMw4OVkYb0AhURyosBHX4xB74QFnoECAMQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.dam.brown.edu%2Fpeople%2Fmumford%2Falg_geom%2Fpapers%2FAGII.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2Wt9E2O8eG4N23R8OBXyRm))):

> **Definition.** If $X$ is an irreducible reduced scheme, $Y\subset X$ an irreducible reduced subscheme and $D$ is a Cartier divisor on $X$, then if $Y\not\subseteq\operatorname{Supp} D$, define $\operatorname{Tr}_Y D$ to be the Cartier divisor on $Y$ whose local equations at $y\in Y$ are just the restrictions to $Y$ of its local equations at $y\in X$.

My questions are:

1. What word does Tr come from?
2. What are the local equations of $D$ at $x\in X$?
3. (Main question) What are the restrictions to $Y$ of the local equations of $D$ at
   $y\in Y$?

For the definition of Cartier divisors in the book, see section 3.6 (page 109 in the draft).

The following are my thought:

1. Trace?
2. I think that a local equation of $D$ at $x\in X$ is an $f$ such that
   $(U,f)$ represents $D$ and such that $x\in U$. In this case (i.e., $X$ integral) $f$ is an element of the function field $\mathbf R(X)$.
3. Then the restriction to $Y$ of a local equation $f$ at $y$ must be an element of $\mathbf R(Y)$. I think this has something to do
   with the surjection $\mathcal O_X \to\mathcal O_Y$, but does it
   induce a map $\mathbf R(X)\to\mathbf R(Y)$ between function fields?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Probably trace, but this is the first time I've seen this construction called that.
2. Yes, that's correct.
3. No, there's no $k$-map $k(X)\to k(Y)$ - any map of fields must be an injection, but the target has smaller transcendence degree than the source (assuming $Y$ is a strict subvariety) which is impossible. Instead, locally on $U\subset X$ write $f=g/h$ where $g,h\in\mathcal{O}_X(U)$. Writing $\overline{g}$ and $\overline{h}$ for the images of $g$ and $h$ under the natural map $\mathcal{O}_X(U)\to \mathcal{O}_Y(Y\cap U)$, the restriction of $f$ to $Y$ is $\overline{g}/\overline{h}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can we say that $\bar h$ is not $0$ in $\mathcal O_Y(Y\cap U)$? Then the assumption $Y\not\subseteq\operatorname{Supp}D$ may be needed.

Comment: The assumption that $Y$ is not contained in the support of $D$ guarantees that we can choose $g,h$ so that neither vanish identically on $Y\cap U$.

Comment: I guess that is what I didn’t understand. I will think more about that. Thank you very much.